# Where can I find examples of blank motion forms?

Tags: process, court

I'm trying to find an example for a blank motion form for requesting the courts perform an action. Anybody have any examples that I can use to type up my request?

Edit: For LaSalle County Illinois

Comment: Where? Different courts have different forms.

Answer (score 1):

For UK courts: Some court applications may require certain forms. If you know what kind of application you want to make, you can cross reference the type of application [here](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part04/pd_part04) and after finding the type of form you want, you can download a pdf/doc copy of the form [here](http://hmctsformfinder.justice.gov.uk/HMCTS/FormFinder.do)

Answer (score 1):

For federal courts, [here](http://www.uscourts.gov/services-forms/forms) are some examples. For Washington state, [here](https://www.courts.wa.gov/forms/) are some forms. These will give you a general idea of what such paperwork might look like. Depending on the court, they may not accept home-formatted and printed forms.

Comment: When I called the court office they said they have no form and I'd have to type up my own.

Comment: As I say, court-dependent. I had to go to a store that sells legal forms.

Answer (score 1):

Illinois has a [variety of standard forms](http://www.illinoiscourts.gov/Forms/approved/default.asp) promulgated by the Illinois Supreme Court.

The standard shell form for a motion is [here](http://www.illinoiscourts.gov/Forms/approved/procedures/motion.asp).